# What string should I pass to the Graph API to post a message with link and image?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

The [documentation for posting a link to a Facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed#publish) has me stumped at this point:

> picture Determines the preview image associated with the link. string

I've tried passing a valid URL and a base_64 encoded image, to no avail. Passing a URL results in the link posting without the image, but without returning any errors. This is what I'm passing in that case, as printed by PHP's `print_r()`:

```
Array
(
    [link] => http://mysite.cl/etc.etc.html
    [name] => test name
    [description] => test description
    [caption] => test caption
    [access_token] => [my_access_token]
    [picture] => http://mysite.cl/app/site/artic/20140909/imag/foto_0000000120140909171931.jpg
)
```

Passing a base_64 encoded image results in an API error:

> (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

What should be the content of the `picture` field?

Comment: That's the output of PHP's print_r, not the actual code, which is quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking some more, I've gathered that posting a complete URL like I am doing is right, but there's [an open bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/483198438473182/) with facebook's safe_image script, the script that caches posted media, and it results in a 1x1px picture. Other questions in the same vein in SO include [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/483198438473182/).